# How to remove all lines in a string starting at one phrase, until a line with different phrase or character is found in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, substring

I am trying to remove all characters/lines starting at one phrase including spaces that works across lines, but the RegEx's i'm using don't seem to be working across multiple lines. In the example, id like to remove all instances of @AlternateMessage('and everything between these parentheses). So essentially everything and all lines starting at @Alternate until a line with }) is found.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction for this?

Example:

```
const str = `
        @Default("Stock ()")
        String Stock(int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Assign()")
        @AlternateMessage({
                "({})", "Assign"
        })
        String Assign(@PluralCount int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Assign()")
        @AlternateMessage({
                "({})", "Assign",
                "=0", "{0} Assign definitions
        })
        String Assign(@PluralCount int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Form")
        String Form();
    `;


const desiredResult = `
        @Default("Stock ()")
        String Stock(int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Assign()")
        String Assign(@PluralCount int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Assign()")
        String Assign(@PluralCount int count);

        @DefaultMessage("Form")
        String Form();
    `;
```

I thought of using something like this .replaceAll(/ @A.*)/g, '') but for one it doesn't work if there is another ) before the closing ) of course, and it also doesn't work across multiple lines. I tried another one to remove the lines starting with @Alternate but I could only get it delete that one line.

Comment: It maybe beyond JS to do balanced text as in the case of `({..({..({..})})..})` So spanning lines is not the issue here.

Comment: What could help you though is all substring content `"here"` is to be ignored plus your statemnt there is no recursion needed. Then it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this pattern with `replaceAll()` in JavaScript:

```
const cleanedStr = str.replace(/@AlternateMessage\([\s\S]*?\)\s*/g, '');
```

This should remove all lines starting with @AlternateMessage and everything between the parentheses, while preserving the rest of the input string.

Comment: Perhaps you did not see the nested parentheses.  This example stops after the first close paren which does not match the open paren.  Except in special cases, regex does not handle nested parentheses, or any other kind of context-sensitive parsing.

Comment: Thanks so much. As mentioned below, it doesn't work with nested parentheses as in my example, but I think it works well enough for my actual use case. Was just trying to account for potential edge cases in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work on regex101 with the ECMAScript flavor.

`^\s*\@AlternateMessage\({\s*(\"[^"]*\"\s*,?\s*)+}\)\n`

https://regex101.com/r/aFgRsZ/1

Does that help?